# Unexpected error from external database driver (1) in .NET WebAPI hosted on Azure app services

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET C# web api application hosted inside Azure App Services. This api reads .xls files from blob storage and stores it inside sql database. I am using following connection string to connect to .xls file.

> var connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fpath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Importmixedtypes=text;typeguessrows=0;\"";

Last week everything was working properly but now I am getting following error

> Unexpected error from external database driver (1)

I also tried to change provider from Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in connection string but I found that it is not supported in Azure App Services. [MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b45b5a13-c212-44ce-b268-228247123a30/the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-for-web-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

I have not changed any code related to this issue. I think the problem is from Microsoft side, they might have run some security updates.

How should I get it fixed. I need help.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/10/18/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-microsoft-jet-database-engine-after-applying-october-security-updates/), it seems that it is caused by OS update. If you are host in the Azure WebApp, please have a try to connect to **Azure support**. As the WebApp is the [Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), we have no access to change the registry or install the  Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for it.

> The JET provider is no longer able to connect after the October update. This update (released October 10th, 2017) includes a security update release that inadvertently affects the JET provider. The update was kb4041678 and included in the patch kb4041681

I also create a new Azure WebApp to use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to read xls file, it also **doesn't work** on the Azure website.

If other way to read .xls in the Azure WebApp is acceptable, you could use [OpenXml SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). How to use the OpenXml SDK, you could refer to this [document](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK).